# OpenSCAD sin() returns wrong result

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, openscad

Trying to create a function which creates a vertex involving some `sin` and `cos` usage.

I'm noticing a discrepancy between what OpenSCAD returns and what the Google calculator returns. Eg:

OpenSCAD:

```
echo(sin(9)); // 0.156434
echo(cos(9)); // 0.987688
```

Whereas with Google:

```
sin(9) = 0.41211848524
cos(9) = -0.91113026188
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but why is there a difference between the two results?

Comment: Google's doing it in radians - your OpenSCAD is doing it in degrees

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google's doing it in radians - OpenSCAD is doing it in degrees

Your code returns the right answer if your input is 9 degrees, rather than radians

```
sin(9 degrees) = 0.15643446504
sin(9 radians) = 0.41211848524
```

For information, a radian is a unit for measuring angles, like the degree, but it is equal to about 57.3 degrees

Comment: Man, I spent way too long on this.